# How to discover workstation or server is installed

Tags: server

Is there a way to discover if an installed OS is workstation or server? Is it just a matter of the packages that are installed or is there some difference that can be detected?

Comment: Depends on how technical you want to be: is a server with desktop to you a workstation or a server?  If the 1st: `/usr/bin/startx` is a command to start the GUI. If present on a system... workstation otherwise server. A couple releases ago the desktop and the server became technically the same system (due to convergence ;) )

Comment: dupe: http://askubuntu.com/questions/12562/how-to-check-if-ubuntu-desktop-or-server-is-installed http://askubuntu.com/questions/434121/how-to-know-if-the-os-is-desktop-or-server-version http://askubuntu.com/questions/31081/whats-the-difference-between-the-server-version-and-the-desktop-version

Answer (score 0):

Just the set of packages installed. You can start off with an Ubuntu Server installation and install `ubuntu-desktop` package to get the desktop OS. There is no guarantee that the absence of a `*-desktop` package implies a server OS, or that the presence of X11 implies a desktop OS.

Answer (score 0):

I did find some interesting files in /var/log/installer:

media-info says "Ubuntu-Server" for the server and just "Ubuntu" for desktop. syslog shows the same information for the "cdrom"

or from the terminal run:

```
cat /var/log/installer/media-info
```

or, if the file doesn't exist, try:

```
cat /var/log/installer/lsb-release
```

Both of these are helpful and I can use them in conjunction with hardware information.